# Finding basis for row space as a subset of row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I was given this question in a test. From my understanding, you can row reduce the matrix in the question (let's call it A) and find "any" basis for the row space but not the basis as a subset of the row vectors of A (by just looking at the leading coefficients of the reduced row form as the order might get off during the process). However, if I put the row vectors in columns (let's call this new matrix B) and row reduced it, I could find the basis as a subset of row vectors of A by just figuring out the column vectors of B which are in the same column number as the leading coefficients in the reduced row form of B. These column vectors will in turn be row vectors of A because that is where we got them from originally.

Please let me know if this procedure is right or anything you'd like to add to it.

Comment: Yes, this is quite correct. The pivot columns of $A^\top$ will give you linearly independent rows of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. Also, is the part about finding basis as a subset of row vectors from the matrix as it is, is true too, right? The order does get off if you do it like that. Because even in this question, doing it this way yields different results than using the pivot columns of A transpose

Comment: Of course, these linearly independent vectors also span, so they form a basis. I do not understand what you mean by order. When you row reduce, you end up with various linear combinations of the rows; it's not just the "order" that's messed up.

Comment: It is good way to identify a subset of rows that forms a basis for the row space.  However it is the sort of thing that has been asked and answered before.  See for example [Column and row space basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413726/column-and-row-space-basis).